# cannot get the value of seconds in HH:mm:ss

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime

I'm converting a `Datetime` value in a `TextBox Control` using `Convert.ToDateTime.ToString("1900-01-01 HH:mm:ss")` but upon checking the breakpoint in `@tmetake` parameter during debugging, it's only getting the value of `"1900-01-01 14:51:00"` instead of `"1900-01-01 14:51:32"` in the database.

Here is the code:

```
string tmtke = Convert.ToDateTime(tmetake.Text)
                          .ToString("1900-01-01 HH:mm:ss");                
conn.Open();
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("UPDATE hcrsward SET crseward = @crseward " +
   "WHERE enccode = @enccode and entryby = @entryby and tmetake = @tmetake", conn);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@enccode", tbox_passed_id.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dtetake", dtetake.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tmetake", tmtke);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@crseward", cw.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@entryby", tbox_docby.Text);                     
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

In what format will i use to generate the correct values from database

Result should be :
`1900-01-01 14:51:32`

not
`1900-01-01 14:51:00`

Comment: What type is `tmetake` in the database?

Comment: I have to agree with the implication of the comment above, i.e. you should not be converting the `DateTime` to a `String` at all because you should be using a time-or date/time-specific data type in the database. If you are using such a data type then using a `string` in your query makes even less sense. That said, what is the actual text in the `Textbox`, i.e. the value of `tmetake.Text`? BTW, why are you calling `ToString` on `Text` when it's already type `string`? Stuff like that is indicative of your not paying attention to details.

Comment: tmetake is DATETIME in database sir.

Comment: the value of tmetake.Text is a datetime value retrieved from database and displayed in a Gridview

Comment: Isn't `tmetake` a `TextBox`?

Comment: Yes its an edit textbox in Gridview  (TextBox tmetake = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("tbox_tmetake") as TextBox;)

Comment: It would be good to use the `SqlDbType.DateTime` while you send the date to Sql from c#. Example:  ` SqlParameter tmtkeDateTimeParam = new SqlParameter("@tmetake",  SqlDbType.DateTime);
tmtkeDateTimeParam.Value = tmtke;
command.Parameters.Add(tmtkeDateTimeParam);`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the comments, i just realized i missed something in the markup page.

I adjusted the code in the markup page and changed the "{0:t}" under  <asp:TextBox ID="tbox_tmetake"> to "{0:T}" to get the seconds  :

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Time Taken">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                     <asp:Label ID="TimeTaken" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("TimeTaken", "{0:t}") %>' SortExpression="Time Taken"> </asp:Label>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <EditItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="tbox_tmetake" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("TimeTaken", "{0:T}") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                </EditItemTemplate>
                                <ItemStyle Wrap="False" />
                            </asp:TemplateField>
```